# is it possible to login via DEVISE using a virtual attribute and username?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, attributes, devise, virtual

I have a multi-client CMS.  Clients have many users and users belong to a client.  Therefore the user model has username and client_id.  The username is unique within the client_id scope.

I want to allow devise to sign the user in based on the username and the client_id, however, being that client_id is an incrementing integer, I would prefer the user to not need to know his client_id.  Rather he should just be able to use the client name which is an attribute of the client model.

I know I can create a method client_handle like so:

```
class User
   def client_handle
      self.client.handle
   end
end
```

is there a way I can configure devise to login using [:username, :client_handle] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create a `client_name` virtual attribute in Users:**

1. Add `client_name` as an attr_accessor:

   attr_accessor :client_name
2. Add `client_name` to attr_accessible:

   attr_accessible :client_name

Tell Devise to use :client_name in the authentication_keys
Modify config/initializers/devise.rb to have:

```
 config.authentication_keys = [ :email, :client_name ]
```

**Overwrite Devise’s find_for_database_authentication method in Users**

For ActiveRecord:

```
 protected

 def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
   conditions = warden_conditions.dup
   client_name = conditions.delete(:client_name)
   email = conditions.delete(:email)
   where(conditions).where(["lower(email) = :value", { :value => email.downcase }]).where(["'user'.'client_id' in (select 'id' from 'clients' where 'clients'.'name' = :value)", {:value => client_name}]).first
 end
```

**And last step is add client_name field to views:**

Make sure you have the Devise views in your project so that you can customize them

Rails 3:

```
rails g devise:views
```

Modify the views
sessions/new.html.erb:

```
  <p><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></p>
+  <p><%= f.label :client_name %><br />
+  <%= f.text_field :client_name %></p>
```

*PS: Instead of your client_handle method use*

```
delegate :handle, :to => :client, :prefix => true
```